Can I create conditional delay for my android touch?
An annoying problem when you need to touch on a link or button on your android screen at the time when an add, notification or system window opens (such as keypad) and you end up touching undesired spot.
My question is can we create an adjustable delay for the areas on screen after anything pops up on it? of course it would be bad for games where you need to click with very short time intervals, hence "adjustable"
I am not a programmer, I need to know if there's developer mode, etc that can do this, if not, why doesn't it exist?

Stack Overflow questions should be about programming problems. You might want to post this question on https://superuser.com/ instead.
